# How to access docker container via its Ip from the host

Tags: docker

I want to be able to access a docker container via its Ip eg the one I can see when I do docker container inspect foo

The reason is I am using zookeeper inside a docker container that is managing two other docker containers running solr. My code (not in docker and I don't at this stage want it to be) calls zookeeper to get the urls of the solr servers which zookeeper reports as the docker containers ip. My code then falls over because calling the docker containers ip from the host fails as it should be calling localhost.

So how can I allow a call to the docker containers ip from the host to be routed correctly. (I am using Docker native for Mac)

Comment: any relevant answer?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using Docker for Mac, so I'm not sure the newest version Docker for Mac is still based on Docker-machine (which based on VirtualBox) or not.

If you can confirm your Docker for Mac is based on VirtualBox, then you probably could get the inet IP of `vboxnet0` network interface via `ifconfig` command. This IP should be used as your calling IP.

Besides, you should know the port number of your Zookeeper container. Normally the exposed port of a container could be configured in docker run command, for example:

```
docker run -p 5000:5001 -i -t ubuntu /bin/bash
```

Where `-p` indicated the exposed port of the container.